# Simple authentification for a single controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to require users to login to view all actions inside of a single controller. I don't need to maintain their identities, so they're gonna use a shared login and password.

In other words I have some users group, who need to access a certain area on the web-site. I want to give them all the same login and password (say, 'username' and 'passw0rd').

This simple auth should only work inside that controller and shouldn't affect other parts of the web-site in any way. And keep in mind that we have forms auth working for the admin area of the web-site and the group of users described above should not see the admin login page, because they need to be sandboxed inside their controller.

What's the best way to achieve it? Maybe I'm thinking in a wrong direction and there is some different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the credentials in web.config file. Note that you can store the credentials as encrypted in web.config as well.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="30" loginUrl="~/Admin/Login">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="user" password="password"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

You can authenticate the user using the `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` method.

For ex.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string name, string password, string returnUrl)
{
   if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(name, password))
   {
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(name, false);
       return Redirect(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? returnUrl : Url.Action("Manage", "Admin"));
   }
   else
       return View();
}
```

You can mark the controller whose actions needs to be authorized using the built-in `Authorize` attribute.

Comment: In the end I used your solution in combination with [Authorize(Users = "username")] on controller. Not exactly what I wanted, but works good enough, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using forms auth already in your app, just create another user account for all your new users and create two roles i.e. *Admin* and *Shared Users*.

Now add an `Authorize` Attribute to your controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Shared Users")
```

And add the role *Admin* to your admin area if not yet there:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")
```

Comment: How can I add a separate login page for "Shared users"?

Comment: You dont have to. But when you want, just copy your current login view  and action to some other place and modify it like you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I would like to see any solution, which will let me to keep this auth system completely isolated.

Comment: What so you mean exactly by *completely isolated*? My approach uses the same user database for admins and users. You can write another login page if you want.

Comment: I really don't won't a complicated solution. I just need to hardcode a single username and password somewhere.

Comment: When you have forms authentication running on your site this is the *simplest* solution!